# Write data from firebase-database to a file through cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have some data in my firebase-database which is collected from phones. Is there any way that I could write these database's data to a file like `.txt, .xls, .doc/docx`, etc. through firebase cloud-functions?

Comment: I don't see why not! While I don't have a specific code example to share, you could trigger a function using a database or an HTTP trigger, then use a Node package that writes to a file, like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/write

Comment: Thanks for that information. To which file format can it be written, only to .txt or can it be stored in the table format files like .xls? And is it stored offline/to my computer? What do you mean by Node package, exactly?

Comment: Is there any turorial?

Comment: @ganudeepreddy Cloud Functions are really just normal node.js code that is triggered by events in Firebase. So if you can find a way to write an Office doc from node.js, you can usually run the same code in a Cloud Function. But there is no pre-cooked recipe that tells you all the steps. I usually start by searching for a package for each step, e.g. "node module for writing Excel sheet" and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

Yup.Absolutely you can.there are lots of modules out there, that perform writing data/images,chart to file ,

The only problem i encountered is functions does not allow you to create a file.

You have to use a *separate* **tmp** directory to create a file.
*Functions* have only read only persmission relating to file system API's